# Where is the reward operation for athens?

Tags: protocol, operation, api, athens

Athens amendment proposal was succesfully integrated as proto004 into the mainnet at level 458753.

The first mined block can be seen here

https://api6.tzscan.io//v3/block/BMWyM6dcDsbsDjcD8iUJYa166mEAFpw9yori2ofSPooBmFqv6uC

However when i look at it i cannot see the context change that awarded 100 xtz to Nomadic Labs address

https://tezos.id/accounts/tz1iSQEcaGpUn6EW5uAy3XhPiNg7BHMnRSXi

As expected from the source code

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/mainnet/src/proto_004_Pt24m4xi/lib_protocol/init_storage.ml#L67

Can somebody explain if there is a trace in the chain of the balance change for account tz1iSQEcaGpUn6EW5uAy3XhPiNg7BHMnRSXi ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happened directly as part of the context "stitching". When a new protocol is activated, an initialization function is called which lets the new protocol performs some housekeeping on the context to make it compatible with the new code base. This can include changing some of the data structures involved in representing the ledger (e.g. roll base) but, in this case, it also involved crediting the account tz1iSQEcaGpUn6EW5uAy3XhPiNg7BHMnRSXi.

Comment: Thanks. For accounting/auditing purpose would it make sense that this context stitching gets a trace as a state transition operation that could be queried on its own ?

Comment: The transition could be made more explicit by creating inflation operations which can only be created in protocol upgrades.